# Why is a vector copy occurring when I try to return a const reference?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm measuring the performance of a little demo I have running *in debug mode*. These operations seem to take a very long time, and are incurring a copy operation (or so it appears while debugging):

```
// Get access to the vertices and faces
auto vertices = t.GetVertices();
auto faces    = t.GetFaces();
```

The implementation of that function is this:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3>  const& GetVertices() const { return vertices_; }
std::vector<glm::ivec3> const& GetFaces()    const { return faces_;    }
```

In a class that contains the following private members:

```
private:
  std::vector<glm::vec3>  vertices_;
  std::vector<glm::ivec3> faces_;
```

For whatever reason, I would expect that returning a const reference would incur almost zero performance penalty, but this operation appears to be really bogging down the program. What am I missing here? Does this get optimized out in release mode, but will always occur in debug mode?

Comment: It's not *returning* that leads to the copy, it is initializing a new variable that leads to the copy.

Comment: First of, since you are return a reference there's no performance penalty, unless you are assigning like this `std::vector<glm::vec3> v = GetVertices();` and not like this `std::vector<glm::vec3> &v = GetVertices();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Why does it copy the contents?

The type of `vertices` and `faces` will be `std::vector<glm::vec3>` and `std::vector<glm::ivec3>`, respectively. When initializing them the compiler is required to copy the contents from the returned references.

The compiler assumes that you don't want the contents of `vertices` to change if the data-member `vertices_` changes; since that's the way you have declared your variables.

---

#### How can I prevent this from happening?

If you'd like to declare them as references you'll have to explicitly say so:

```
auto const& vertices = t.GetVertices ();
auto const& faces    = t.GetFaces ();
```

---

#### How is the type of `faces` and `vertices` deduced?

Having the expression `auto foo = init`, `foo` will have the type that is deduced for the argument of the following template function, called as `deduce_type (init)` as its parameter.

```
template<class T> void deduce_type (T);
```

```
                               // auto vertices = t.getVertices ();
deduce_type (t.getVertices ()) // imaginary call, T = std::vector<glm::vec3>
```

---

#### Is there some workaround so that I'd always get the exact type?

No, not currently, but in upcoming Standard of *C++* (*C++14*) you will be able to do the below, and the result will be what you inaccurately expected your original code to do:

```
decltype(auto) vertices = t.GetVertices ();
//              ^-- vertices is of type `std::vector<glm::vec3> const&`
```

Comment: Interesting -- I assumed that `auto` just kind of magically matched up the data type to whatever was returned by the relevant function call. That's obviously not the case. How is the data type of `auto` determined? For instance, if the function returned a const pointer, would the auto data type still be a regular vector?

Comment: @aardvarkk, It's the same as template type deduction.

Comment: @chris It looks like template type deduction is a fairly complex subject in itself. Is there some kind of rule of thumb I can remember to make sure I don't screw this up again?

Comment: @aardvarkk `auto` will never be deduced to be a reference, const nor an array. (You can add references and const as demonstrated in refp's answer, but not arrays btw.) References and `const` is dropped, array decays to pointer.

Comment: `auto&&` comes very close to the exact type (it conflates rvalues and rvalue references)

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that assigning or initializing an object with/to another, will (in some way or another) end in a copy of that object.  While the functions you give do return constant references, they are assigned (or copied) to new instantiations.

You can avoid this by useing a pointer (which will allocate memory on the stack for the pointer, but IMO it's a nominal factor), or you could use a move-constructor.  I don't know if I move constructor would work, in this case, but my initial thoughts are that it wouldn't (since the assigned value is supposed to be const).